# (Reopened) Reopen Request: "For any CEO role, which core responsibilities are never delegated, independently from the company?"

Tags: support, reopen-request, trolling

My [new question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/182246/for-any-ceo-role-which-core-responsibilities-are-never-delegated-independently) has been closed.
The reason:
"
Questions seeking advice on company-specific regulations, agreements, or policies should be directed to your manager or HR department. Questions that address only a specific company or position are of limited use to future visitors. Questions seeking legal advice should be directed to legal professionals.
"

My question was:

- NOT about a specific company, regulation, agreement or policy
- NOT about a specific company
- NOT about a specific position, but about the GENERAL role of CEO, including the core responsibilities which do NOT depend on the company
- NOT seeking legal advice

This question was perfectly valid and the close votes are nothing more than trolling and/or toxic behaviour. This would be a good time to start moderating "close vote enthusiasts".

Comment: You posted two CEO questions lately, which one are you talking about? Both have already votes to reopen BTW... It's no news folks sometimes close things swiftly here, but that's the reason why we have Meta, and Votes to reopen and [chat]

Comment: There is no valid reason this question should have been closed. Despite the close reason, there is nothing company specific about it, and it isn't asking a legal question. **I voted to reopen**.

Comment: Agree that it's sort of an XY question. While there's no fixed set answers can still mention "usually includes". Given that motosubatsu expressed interest in reopening I've gone ahead and reopened it at 3/5.  For future reference: it can be useful to link to your own previously closed post in a comment but explain how you've rescoped the question so it's on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't VTC this - while they're *aren't* any such fixed "core responsibilities" asking whether there is such a thing is (IMO) perfectly valid for someone who didn't know that and FWIW I think Joe Strazzere's answer does good job of explaining not only that there aren't but *why* there aren't.

You might have been better off editing your previous question into the "improved" version and requesting a re-opening - posting another "new" question can get messy - the old one currently has 2 reopen votes and the new one 1 for example.

As for re-opening - if it gets to 4 Reopen votes I'll be more than happy to cast the 5th.

Answer (score -2):

[What topics can I ask about here?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

> What questions are off topic here?
>
> ...
>
> - Questions that lack a clear goal we can address

[What type of questions should I avoid asking?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

> ***avoid* asking subjective questions where …**
>
> ...
>
> - there is no actual problem to be solved:

Also,

> the close votes are nothing more than trolling and/or toxic behaviour. This would be a good time to start moderating "close vote enthusiasts".

Actually lol. Thanks for the laugh!